# chromium build error-package org.chromium.mojom.payments does not exist

Tags: java, android, chromium

As the subject line says, I couldn’t find the sources for the mojom payment package while compiling chromium for android.

Here are the list of errors.

```
../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/mojo/ChromeServiceRegistrar.java:11: error: package org.chromium.mojom.payments does not exist
import org.chromium.mojom.payments.PaymentRequest;
                              ^
../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/payments/AutofillAddress.java:9: error: package org.chromium.mojom.payments does not exist
import org.chromium.mojom.payments.ShippingAddress;
                              ^
../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/payments/AutofillAddress.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
public ShippingAddress toShippingAddress() {
       ^
symbol:   class ShippingAddress
location: class AutofillAddress
../chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/payments/AutofillPaymentInstrument.java:13: error: package org.chromium.mojom.payments does not exist
```